# Dynamically control hover with dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

I would like the materialize menu to drop down on *hover* for larger screens but for smaller screens only want the drop down to show when clicking the menu item (the default of .dropdown() is `hover: false`).

I am using materialize css jQuery.  I have tried to dynamically enable *hover* based on code to detect screen size, and upon that either allow `hover: true` or no `hover: false`.  This is not working, the hover property is active on ALL screen sizes.

```
    if ($( window ).width() > 975)
    {
        $('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown({hover: true});
    }

    else
    {
        $('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown();
    }
```

When menu is displaying in smaller screen sizes I do not want the hover functionality - only on large screen sizes.